# Why am I getting error code 81 while trying to run Aerospike backup with admin user and default roles assigned?

Tags: aerospike

While taking aerospike backup, I'm getting below error even though I'm using admin user and I assigned all default roles to admin user.

"error while running scan for 4096 partitions from 0 to 4095 - code 81:AEROSPIKE_ROLE_VIOLATION at src/main/aerospike/aerospike_scan.c:352"

Could you please let me know what else I should provide the permissions?

I tried providing all default roles assigned to admin user but still giving the same error. I am not sure if I need to provide permissions on namespaces to the admin user.

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to fix the issue by providing read & write role to user which is using to run the backup.

manage acl grant user admin roles read-write